# Search automatically on website and get their content

Tags: java, php, html, web, vs-web-site-project

For my project, i need to insert an EAN (Productcode like 4009900508599) on this website: codecheck.info
In a normal case it isnt really an problem, because you can send the content directly to the website.
On this website, the call is:

```
https://www.codecheck.info/product.search?q=4009900508599&r=03AOLTBLSbwq8TlZl9bDf72tOekXcyrp8vCBu6pgfYvI-0fuFv40FWCX5XX5Z9DTOlo0J-l3WGmSRRUMmxGLl_oO9miNeJExZsrZwbaFFDovw5FrOMaM2CeuOTFQOMr4q__ixGx7jV7509DF_y7Y19maVN40kuCrjIE7JCV7p3uiu4DhOgU6BVlW8O5yrx8px7_fknOwseOiLXIFbxDlbZ6nD-67765YdL6zOiyoH3nHL1LO1L0_GQQkPOrP3QnjXHjjaDzg_RYT48cvkGnt3ER-8AUwB9LPwP-9OJp4uWzxtG-TiWngZEwzcJDJS4FEfsd2Xq2taU7sOhZquEiwi4pFdXQgAwb0PRYNEv9GR1tBb0LYnHUiF9LLMwOhvL3pnaididlwl--jMP_-ZvSnK04EHIKYKQm5CLPbgcfs68iC4GtWnLv63g6hD_W_1kElHdhR3rT_VdAhkjESo7CGcmUyKJ_TVw3Xy4rOZS8t3TCJSux98-otnmJh4
```

With q=03A... they generate some stuff, that i cant know. 
So my question is, does someone know a way to insert the number into the searchbox automatically and get their content?

Comment: Looks like CSRF protection, which is supposed to prevent you from doing exactly that.

Comment: I know. but is there a possible work around?

Comment: They is most likely a reason they have such protection in place, meaning you are not allowed to do what you want to do!